# Codeigniter- call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Error' does not have a method 'index'

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have developed a delivery service application on CodeIgniter, at localhost, it is running without any errors(using MAMP Pro).

Now I have decided to upload it to my domain at Dreamhost, I have configured it, Logged in successfully but when I am clicking on customers or employees it is giving the following error;

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
> callback, class 'Error' does not have a method 'index'
>
> Filename: core/CodeIgniter.php
>
> Line Number: 532
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home/dh_yg2qtz/aquamanager/index.php Line: 315 Function:
> require_once

my customer model code is:

```
class customer extends BaseController {
var $ascustr = 'ASCU-';

     public function __construct()
        {
             parent::__construct();
             //$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->library('form_validation');
                 $this->load->model('user_model');
        $this->isLoggedIn();  
            $this->load->helper('url');
            $this->load->model('customer_model','customer');
        }

    public function index()
    {
    $this->global['pageTitle'] = 'CodeInsect : Customer Managemwnt';
        $customers=$this->customer->get_all_customers(); 
        //$products=$this->customer->get_all_products();
        $deliverydays=$this->customer->get_all_deliverydays();
        $employees=$this->customer->get_all_employees();
        $referenceperson=$this->customer->get_all_references();

        $data ['customers'] = $customers;
        $data ['deliverydays'] = $deliverydays;
        $data ['employees'] = $employees;
        $data ['referenceperson'] = $referenceperson;
        $this->loadCustomers("/customers/customer_view", $this->global, $data, NULL);
        //$this->loadViews("customers/customer_view", $this->global,  $data);
        
    }
```

Please help me to resolve the issue, I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: can you show where and how you call the php function call_user_func_array()? did you try to debug where you are calling it?

Comment: in the local environment, it is working without any issue.

Comment: Well, there's clearly a difference in your hosted environment. So you need to find what it is. Anyway we can't really help you at the moment because you didn't show us the code containing the use of call_user_func_array(). Please show that code (the version in your hosted environment).

Comment: Why is your Class spelt all lower case as in customer and not as specified with Capital First, so it should be Customer and also the Case of the Filenames is important. If you developed on Windows and then uploaded to an apache/linux server - it is expecting the case to be correct.

Comment: I have capitalized the first letter of class Customer,  call_user_func_array(array(&$CI, $method), $params);

Comment: I know the there is a minor issue because in the application, User List, Edit User, Add User working properly. I can upload here Complete Controller file and Model file if needed, just help to resolve the issue please